# Math.round with infinity in java

Tags: java

I am trying to get a valid response for

```
Math.round(Double.valueOf(1) / Double.valueOf(0))
```

but I am getting a random number as output. Can someone please help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's behaving exactly as [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round-double-) - you're not getting "a random number", you're getting `Long.MAX_VALUE`:

> If the argument is positive infinity or any value greater than or equal to the value of `Long.MAX_VALUE`, the result is equal to the value of `Long.MAX_VALUE`.

In your case, the argument *is* positive infinity. Hence the result.